# android behavior not work in androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

i have a `CoordinatorLayout` and have `AppBarLayout` in it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Pages.Artist.Show">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/AppBar">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:id="@+id/ArtistImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In `NestedScrollView` i ***can't*** set **layout_behavior**!

Why we do not have layout_behavior it in androidx ??

Comment: Just add app:layout_behavior="...." in the NestedScrollView. Where is the problem?

Comment: i can not use it beacuse android studio can not undestand it !

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout behavior like this in **NestedScrollView** tag.

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"